# Options in style files

Tags: package-writing

How can I have an option to require some packages in a style file I am writing ?

For instance, I can have a Science and Technology Option that makes available certain symbols.  And another option to allow use of different fonts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) currently lists more than 18,000 [!] symbols, which can be accessed via suitable `\usepackage` directives. It's up to you to determine which packages ought to be loaded when you specify an option called, say, "ScienceAndTechnology" as an optional argument for the `\documentclass` directive.